# How to split a string in SQL query after a specific character

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT wp.id,
   w.course_id,
   wt.slug,
   wp.post_title,
   w.course_id,
   w.start_date,
   wp.post_name,
   w.end_date,
   w.duration,
   w.timings,
   w.timezone,
   w.reg_link
FROM       wp_posts wp
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON wt.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt     ON wt.term_id=wtt.term_id
    AND wtt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id
    AND tr.object_id=wp.id
JOIN wp_event_list w 
    ON trim(wp.post_title) = trim(
       substring(w.course_id, position('-' IN w.course_id)+1,LENGTH (w.course_id)))
WHERE w.end_date >= CURRENT_DATE
    AND wp.post_type ='event'
    AND wtt.taxonomy = 'EventCategory'
GROUP BY w.id
ORDER BY w.start_date, w.timings ASC
```

In this query for `w.timings` I have a value like this "8:30 AM - 10:00 AM". I want to display `w.timings` column value like "8:30 AM".
How to split and display this string in above query?

I am using MySQL 5.6 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

It returns the substring before the # occurrence of the delimiter.

```sql
SUBSTRING_INDEX(w.timings, ' - ', 1) as timings
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e408bea56aec409b641659e833612662) demo

Comment: where to add this line in above query?